# How to normalize percentages in python

Tags: python, math, numpy, dictionary, percentage

I have a list of dictionaries in python signifying country code and hits percentages for different servers.

```
[{'country': 'BR', 'values': {'Server1': [100.0, 100.0]}},
 {'country': 'IE', 'values': {'Server1': [61.7868], 'Server2': [38.2132]}},
 {'country': 'US', 'values': {'Server1': [82.19], 'Server2': [100.0]}}]
```

I would like to convert it to a single value keeping the percentages intact. So I added up the values in the list and divided them by their length as in

```
for key_dict in resp:
averages = {}
for name, numbers in key_dict['values'].items():
    averages[name] = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
key_dict['values'] = averages
```

But this does not add up to the correct percentages in most cases. For instance,the above solution would result into.

```
[{'country': 'BR', 'values': {'Server1': [100.0]}},
 {'country': 'IE', 'values': {'Server1': [61.7868], 'Server2': [38.2132]}},
 {'country': 'US',
  'values': {'Server1': [100.0, 92.8571, 100.0, 100.0, 18.1078],
             'Server2': [100.0, 100.0]}}]
```

So clearly for 'US`sum both the`Server1`and`Server2` exceeds 100 . How do I divide the percentages clearly here in python.

Comment: The last time I checked, neither 100.0 or 82.19 exceeds 100.  Could you clarify the question please

Comment: The sum exceeds 100 , ideally sum of both the servers should be 100 to get the percentage split.

Comment: Could you clarify the question.  Why does the value for `'Server1'` in country `'BR'` have two values while all the others have 1?  Can you give us a sample output that you would like for the example input you have provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do first calculate the average percentage within a server. Then you want to modify that average to be representative of the average time across all of the servers within in a given country. So for "BR" you would divide that average by 1 server, but for the other two you would divide by 2 servers. This can be done by doing the following:

```
resp = [{"country": "BR", "values": {"Server1": [100.0, 100.0]}},
    {"country": "IE", "values": {"Server2": [38.2132], "Server1": [61.7868]}},
    {"country": "US", "values": {"Server2": [100.0, 100.0],
    "Server1":[100.0, 92.8571, 100.0, 100.0, 18.1078]}}]

for d in resp:
    num_severs = len(d['values'])
    for s in d['values']:
        # Calculate average pct for each server
        avg_pct = sum(d['values'][s]) / len(d['values'][s])

        # Equalize the average
        d['values'][s] = avg_pct / num_severs
```

This would modify `resp` to be:

```
[{'country': 'BR', 'values': {'Server1': 100.0}}, {'country': 'IE', 'values': {'Server1': 30.8934, 'Server2': 19.1066}}, {'country': 'US', 'values': {'Server1': 41.09649, 'Server2': 50.0}}]
```